# Zend_Form_Element_Captcha - Reload

Tags: zend-framework, captcha

how could I add a "reload captcha"-feature?
How I could change the image element with JavaScript I know, but how should I manage that with the ZF? I generate the captcha with Zend_Form_Element_Captcha as an Image.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to use [ReCaptcha](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.recaptcha.html) using [Zend_Form_Element_Captcha](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.captcha). ReCaptcha has its own feature to reload images, etc.